Intuitive derivation of Rodrigues formula for Legendre polynomials
In a lot of references involving Legendre polynomials I've seen the Rodrigues formula used as the most fundamental tool used to study these functions. A few posts on this site talk about how to prove that the formula, namely that $$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$$ satisfies $$\frac{d}{dx}(1-x^2)\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)+n(n+1)f_n(x)=0$$
When we start from the result, it is not too difficult to show this. However, I am somewhat dumbfounded as to how this result was derived originally--it seems very much not obvious whatsoever. I am wondering how we can infer that an equation of this type satisfies the above differential equation without starting from the Rodrigues formula? I am assuming that this formula wasn't derived from a lucky observation, such as what is used in this post.

I don't know, but if I had to guess, I would guess that Rodrigues started from a differential equation (I don't know which equation).

@QiaochuYuan maybe my title was a little too strict, I was trying to ask how one would derive the formula without prior knowledge (perhaps Rodrigues had some divine insight while a more elegant/intuitive derivation exists while still not assuming the solution is of the stated form)—updated the title to reflect this

I decided to reconstruct Rodrigues' own derivation in his 1815 dissertation, beginning on page 375 here. (The text is in French, so I'll credit the presentation by Grattan-Guinness as an interpretative guide). He begins from the Legendre differential equation in Sturm-Liouville form
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[(1-x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}\right]+\ell(\ell+1)y(x)=0\tag{1}$$ whose (bounded) solutions are the Legendre polynomials $P_\ell(x)$.
(In fact, Rodrigues begins from the associated version of the above equation and thus his argument covers the associated Legendre polynomials $P_{\ell,m}(x)$. But this requires an additional substitution $z= (1-x^2)^{-m/2} y$, so for the interest of a simpler argument I'll stick with the ordinary $m=0$ case alone. Rodrigues also has $(m,n)$ instead of $(\ell,m)$ but I will stick to modern notation.)
Suppose we now take $p$ derivatives of (1) with respect to $x$. Focusing on the first term in (1), the general Leibniz rule yields
\begin{align}
\frac{d^{p+1}}{dx^{p+1}}\left[(1-x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}\right]
&=\sum_{k=0}^{p+1} \binom{p+1}{k}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(1-x^2)\cdot \frac{d^{p-k+2}y }{dx^{p-k+2}}\\
&=(1-x^2)\frac{d^{p+2}y }{dx^{p+2}}+(p+1)(-2x)\frac{d^{p+1}y }{dx^{p+1}}+\frac{p(p+1)}{2}(-2)\frac{d^{p}y }{dx^{p}}\\
\end{align}
Therefore the $p$th derivative of (1) yields
\begin{align}
0&=\frac{d^{p+1}}{dx^{p+1}}\left[(1-x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}\right]+\ell(\ell+1)\frac{d^py}{dx^p}\\
&=(1-x^2)\frac{d^{p+2}y }{dx^{p+2}}+(p+1)(-2x)\frac{d^{p+1}y }{dx^{p+1}}+(\ell-p)(\ell+p+1)\frac{d^{p}y }{dx^{p}}\end{align}
Multiplying both sides by $(1+x^2)^p$ and rearranging yields
\begin{align}
-(\ell-p)(\ell+p+1)(1-x^2)^p \frac{d^{p}y }{dx^{p}}
&=(1-x^2)^{p+1}\frac{d^{p+2}y }{dx^{p+2}}+(p+1)(-2x)(1-x^2)^p\frac{d^{p+1}y }{dx^{p+1}}\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[(1-x^2)^{p+1}\frac{d^{p+1}y}{dx^{p+1}}\right]\hspace{4cm} (2)
\end{align}
(Note that Rodrigues omits the manipulations just described and instead states (2) as resulting from $p$-fold differentiation of (1).) In the $p=\ell$ case, this further simplifies to
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[(1-x^2)^{\ell+1}\frac{d^{\ell+1}y}{dx^{\ell+1}}\right]=0$$
from which we deduce $$(1-x^2)^{\ell+1}\frac{d^{\ell+1}y}{dx^{\ell+1}}=B\implies  \frac{d^{\ell}y}{dx^{\ell}}=A+B\int \frac{dx}{(1-x^2)^{\ell+1}}\tag{3}$$
where $A,B$ are constants of integration. This implies polynomial solutions for $y$ whenever $B=0$, whereas the $A=0$ case gives rise to the Legendre functions of the second kind $Q_n(x)$.
Rodrigues now returns to equation (2). If we rearrange this as
$$(1-x^2)^p \frac{d^{p}y }{dx^{p}}=-\frac{1}{(\ell-p)(\ell+p+1)}\frac{d}{dx}\left[(1-x^2)^{p+1}\frac{d^{p+1}y}{dx^{p+1}}\right]$$
Note that the expression being differentiated in case $p$ is the same as the expression not being differentiated in case $p+1$. As such, we may proceed inductively on $p=0,1,2,\ldots,\ell-1$ to get
\begin{align}
y&=-\frac{1}{\ell(\ell+1)}\frac{d}{dx}\left[(1-x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}\right]\\
&=-\frac{1}{\ell(\ell+1)}\times -\frac{1}{(\ell-1)(\ell+2)}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[(1-x^2)^2 \frac{d^2 y}{d^2 x}\right]\\
&~~\vdots\\
&=\frac{(-1)^\ell}{(2\ell)!}\frac{d^\ell}{dx^\ell }\left[(1-x^2)^{\ell} \frac{d^\ell y}{d^\ell x}\right]
\end{align}
Combining this with the integral representation (3), we have
$$y=\frac{(-1)^\ell}{(2\ell)!}\frac{d^\ell}{dx^\ell }\left\{(1-x^2)^{\ell}\left[ A+B\int \frac{dx}{(1-x^2)^{\ell+1}}\right]\right\}$$
If we again specialize to the polynomial case ($B=0$) we conclude that
$$y=\frac{(-1)^\ell A}{(2\ell)!}\frac{d^\ell}{dx^\ell }(1-x^2)^{\ell}$$
which (up to the normalization constant) is indeed Rodrigues' formula.

In the interest of historical accuracy I've preserved the order of Rodrigues' arguments. That said, my own preference here would be to switch the order a bit and start from the formula $$(1-x^2)^p \frac{d^{p}y }{dx^{p}}=-\frac{1}{(\ell-p)(\ell+p+1)}\frac{d}{dx}\left[(1-x^2)^{p+1}\frac{d^{p+1}y}{dx^{p+1}}\right]$$ which is valid for $0\leq p\leq \ell-1$. From this we proceed inductively to express $y$ as the $\ell$th derivative of $d^\ell y/dx^\ell$; handling the $p=\ell$ case separately then shows that there exist solutions with constant $d^\ell y/dx^\ell$ which yields Rodrigues formula.

Very interesting.

Rodrigues' formula can be considered as built on an iterative application of Rolle's theorem.
Consider the figure below :

Fig. 1 : Graphical representations of the functions in the table below (to be read from left to right and top from bottom) starting with $Q(x)=(x^2-1)^5$. At each new differentiation, Rolle's theorem warrants new roots interlaced with the previous ones. The last curve is the curve of the fifth Legendre polynomial $P_5(x)$.
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{pol.}&\text{total degree}&\text{degree of roots} \pm1&\text{number of roots in } (-1,1)\\
\hline
Q(x)=(x^2-1)^5&10&2 \times 5&0\\
\frac{1}{1.1!}Q'(x)&9&2 \times 4&1\\
\frac{1}{2.2!}Q''(x)&8&2 \times 3&2\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
\frac{1}{2^5 5!}Q^{(5)}(x)&5&2 \times 0&5\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
Please note the flatness of the initial curve in points $-1$ and $1$ due to the high degree of multiplicity of these roots,
"Sage" program for the generation of Fig. 1 (with a division by $2k$ at each step in order to have a global division by $2^n n!$) :
n=5;a=1.3
Q=(x^2-1)^n
for k in [1..n+1] :
   g=plot(Q,(x,-a,a),ymin=-a,ymax=a);show(g)
   Q=diff(Q/(2*k),x);


The comment I'd make is that framing this as "what Rodrigues may have been thinking" is not especially plausible: his own reasoning starts from the Legendre differential equation and is based on some (rather involved and non-obvious) derivative manipulations. It also just doesn't seem necessary: whether the argument gives sufficient intuition doesn't really depend on what Rodrigues thought.

@Semiclassical I agree. This kind of "reverse-engineering" exercise shouldn't be turned into "reverse-state-of-mind" ...

The Legendre equation is the spherical part of the Laplacian in case that the solution does not depend on the azimut $\phi$
$$\Delta_{r,\theta, \phi} = \frac{1}{r^2} \ \left( \partial_r r^2 \partial_r+ \frac{1}{\sin \theta} \ \partial_\theta \sin \theta \partial_\theta +\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta } \ \partial_\phi^2\right),\quad  d\mu = r^2 \ \sin \theta \  dr \ d\theta \ d\phi $$
If one introduces a metric unit coordinate $z=\cos \theta$ on axis of the unit sphere, we have
$$\frac{1}{\sin\theta }\ \partial_\theta \ \sin \theta \ \partial_\theta = \partial_z (1-z^2) \partial_z, \quad  d\mu = r ^2 \ dr \  dz \ d\phi$$
The eigenvalue problem of waves or diffusion with axial symmetry on the unit sphere demands the eigensystem of
$$(\partial_t^2 \ - \  \partial_z \ (1\ - \ z^2)\ \partial_z) \ e^{i \omega_n t} \ Y(n,z)=0$$
$$(\omega_n^2 \ + \  \partial_z \ (1\ - \ z^2)\ \partial_z) \  \ Y(n,z)=0$$
The negative of the second order operator with appropriate boundary conditions at the poles $z=\pm 1$ is symmetrical and positve by  integration by parts with vanishing boundary values for bounded functions.
$$-\int_{-1}^1  f^* \partial_z \ (1-z^2) \partial_z\ g ) \ dz = \int_{-1}^1 (\partial_z\ f^*)\   (1-z^2)\  \partial_z g \ dz.$$
It follows, that $-\partial_z \ (1-z^2) \partial_z$  has a discrete positive spectrum.
Rodrigues formula can be verified easly in the trigonometic version
$$P_n(\cos \theta) = \frac{1}{n!!} \ (\frac{1}{\sin \theta} \partial_\theta )^n \sin^{2n},$$
that Fourier expanded yields orthogonal sums of $\cos(k \ \theta), \sin(k \ \theta), \ k \in \mathbb N, 0\le k\le n$$
